# How do I print a hex number representing a IEEE 754 float as a float in ruby

Tags: ruby, ieee-754

I am using ruby to parse a datastream, some parts of which are IEEE-754 floats, but am not sure how to print these as floats. For example:

```
f = 0xbe80fd31 # -0.2519317
puts "%f" % f
3196124465.000000
```

how do I get `-0.2519317` ?

Answer (score 3):

Any time your converting a binary byte stream to something else, you usually end up using [`String#unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) (and [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) if you're going the other way).

If you have these *bytes*:

```
bytes = [0xbe, 0x80, 0xfd, 0x31]
```

then you could say:

```
bytes.map(&:chr).join.unpack('g')
# [-0.25193169713020325]
```

and then unwrap the array. This:

```
bytes.map(&:chr).join
```

packs the bytes into the string:

```
"\xbe\x80\xfd\x31"
```

which is suitable for `#unpack`. You could also (thanks [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan)) say:

```
# Variations on getting the bytes into a string for `#unpack`
bytes.pack('C4').unpack('g').first
[0xbe80fd31].pack('L>').unpack('g').first

# Variations using `#unpack1`
bytes.map(&:chr).join.unpack1('g')
bytes.pack('C4').unpack1('g')
[0xbe80fd31].pack('L>').unpack1('g')
```

If you already have the string then you go can straight to `#unpack` or `#unpack1`.

You'll want to use `'e'` instead of `'g'` your bytes are in a different order and `'E'` or `'G'` if you actually have an eight byte double rather than a four byte float.

Comment: There's also `unpack1` which returns the first element right away. And you could use `pack` for the first conversion, e.g. `bytes.pack('C4')` or `[0xbe80fd31].pack('L>')`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, didn't even know about `#unpack1`